# Upload to Firebase Storage private bucket without authentication

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I'm using FirebaseStorage to store my app's files and I set my bucket rule as private

```
 `allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth != null`
```

but I dont want user to authenticate, or use any authentication step(like custom token). Is there any way to do???

Comment: Then why not set your rules to allow unauthenticated users?

Comment: if set my bucket to public then everyone can read/write to my bucket and I dont want that.
I tried to write new code with diff package name, diff googler-service file and still can read/write file on my bucket